# calcium and Iron

Tags: calcium

I was anemic few years back though I used to take lots of greens and iron rich food. Someone told me that Iron  and calcium if taken together, only one will get absorbed and for me Iron was not absorbed. 
I used to take greens with curd and dates with milk. Is that the real reason? 
Is it true that calcium and iron should not be taken together ?

Comment: Just a note - The only real way for the body to get rid of excess iron is through blood loss, so make sure that you *need* iron supplementation before taking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search for «taking iron and calcium supplements together» turns up a lot of results that agree with each other on this topic:

- http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/druginfo/natural/912.html says: Calcium makes it harder for the body to absorb iron either from food or supplements. However, in people who have enough stored iron, this probably isn't a problem. But if you are iron deficiWait at least two hours before or after your iron supplement before taking your calcium supplement, if you take iron. ent or might become iron deficient, minimize this interaction by separating your intake of calcium and iron. Don't take calcium supplements at mealtime or when you take iron supplements.
- http://www.wikihow.com/Best-Absorb-Calcium-Supplements says: Wait at least two hours before or after your iron supplement before taking your calcium supplement, if you take iron.
- http://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/iron-supplement-oral-route-parenteral-route/precautions/drg-20070148 says: Do not take iron supplements and antacids or calcium supplements at the same time. It is best to space doses of these 2 products 1 to 2 hours apart, to get the full benefit from each medicine or dietary supplement.

For me, Mayo Clinic is a very reputable source.